# Error When Creating Directory And New Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

So i have a VBA script that takes user input via userform then creates an output workbook to contain the data and saves it as a .csv. The issue im having is when i want to create the folder that the files will be saved into the directory is not the same for each workstation because my company uses Microsoft One Drive which changes the file path for the desktop. I have gotten this to work on my machine but every time i send my form to a user for testing they receive a runtime error and the application cannot create the folder on the desktop. on one occasion the folder was saved in "My Documents" when that is nowhere in my code. Hope you can help.

i have changed my code several times using if statements to verify the file path but i still see the same issue

```
User = Environ("Username") 'set the current users username to the User variable

WBpath = "C:\Users\" & User & "\OneDrive - CompanyName\Desktop" 'windows directory where the file will go
WBpath2 = "C:\Users\" & User & "\Desktop" 'windows directory where the file will go

WBName = "BulkUpload" & UserForm1.TextBox5.value & ".csv" 'the name of the file

WBFile = WBpath & "\BulkUploadFiles\" & WBName 'full file path we will be saving the file in
WBFile2 = WBpath2 & "\BulkUploadFiles\" & WBName 'full file path we will be saving the file in

For Each wb In Workbooks 'loop through each open excel workbook and perform the below action
    If wb.Name = WBName Then 'perform the below action only if the currently selected workbook has the same name as the output workbook
        Workbooks(WBName).Close 'close the selected excel workbook
    End If 'done checking if the file is already open
Next 'go to the next open excel workbook

'make the directory to save the bulkupload file to. create it if it doesnt already exist.

If Dir(WBpath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then 'check is the folder already exists

    ChDir WBpath 'change the directory to WBPath

    If Dir(WBpath & "\BulkUploadFiles\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir "BulkUploadFiles" 'create the output folder
    End If

    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add 'create the output workbook

    With NewBook 'set the properties for the output workbook
        .Title = WBName 'add the workbook title
        .Subject = WBName 'add the workbook subject
        .SaveAs filename:=WBFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True 'save the output workbook to the assigned directory as a CSV file
    End With 'done setting file properties

End If

If Dir(WBpath2, vbDirectory) <> "" Then 'check is the folder already exists

    ChDir WBpath2 'change the directory to WBPath2

    If Dir(WBpath2 & "\BulkUploadFiles\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir "BulkUploadFiles" 'create the output folder
    End If

    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add 'create the output workbook

    With NewBook 'set the properties for the output workbook
        .Title = WBName 'add the workbook title
        .Subject = WBName 'add the workbook subject
        .SaveAs filename:=WBFile2, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True 'save the output workbook to the assigned directory as a CSV file
    End With 'done setting file properties

End If

Workbooks(WBName).Sheets("BulkUpload" & UserForm1.TextBox5.value).Name = "Sheet1" 'rename the first sheet in the output workbook back to Sheet1 so we can reference it correctly later

Workbooks(WBName).Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Sheet3" 'add a new sheet to the output workbook

Workbooks(WBName).Sheets("Sheet3").Visible = xlSheetHidden 'hide the new sheet we just made (Sheet3)
```

on my workstation (with one drive installed) this works fine but on other users pcs i receive an error when attempting to create the folder and fil

Comment: You don't need to use ChDir if you always supply the complete path to (eg) `MkDir`.  ChDir is problemmatic if there are multiple drives present.  Same goes for providing full pathto `SaveAs`

Comment: i did that to prevent it from saving to the documents folder which it was doing on my coworkers workstation when i asked her to test the app for me. i will remove it and see if that makes any difference. how should i save the file if i shouldnt provide the full path to saveas? should i just use "\OneDrive - CompanyName\Desktop" and "\Desktop" or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
ChDir WBpath 'change the directory to WBPath

If Dir(WBpath & "\BulkUploadFiles\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir "BulkUploadFiles" 'create the output folder
End If
```

You can skip the `ChDir` and just use something like this:

```
fPath = WBpath & "\BulkUploadFiles"
If Dir(fPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir fPath 
End If
```

`ChDir` does not set the working folder if the user's current working folder is on a different drive

**EDIT**: this worked for me but I'm not sure what you want to do when adding multiple sheets to a CSV-format file, since a CSV can have only one "sheet"

```
Dim deskTop, wbName As String, folderName As String, newBook As Workbook
Dim txtVal As String

txtVal = UserForm1.TextBox5.Value

deskTop = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")

wbName = "BulkUpload" & txtVal & ".csv" 'the name of the file

'close the workbook if it's open
On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if the file is not open
Workbooks(wbName).Close
On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors

folderName = deskTop & "\BulkUploadFiles\"
If Len(Dir(folderName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir folderName

Set newBook = Workbooks.Add 'create the output workbook

With newBook
    .Title = wbName
    .Subject = wbName
    .SaveAs Filename:=folderName & wbName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True
    .Sheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"
    '??? a csv file can't have multiple sheets...
    '.Sheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Sheet3"
    '.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Visible = xlSheetHidden
End With
```

Comment: You could try using something like `CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")` to find the user's Desktop folder.

Comment: OK as long as you don't need to save it in the file when you close it...

Comment: Ok your code works great for finding the desktop location which is one of the biggest hurdles ive been dealing with on this. Thanks for that. I do need to save the file within the newly created folder but im sure i can figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code. I tried using if statements to validate the path but this is still failing on every workstation except mine.

```
Dim NewBook As Variant
Dim WBpath, WBpath2, WBName, WBFile, WBFile2, WBDir, WBDir2, Fpath, Fpath2 As String
Dim User As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

User = Environ("Username") 'set the current users username to the User variable

WBpath = "C:\Users\" & User & "\OneDrive - CompanyName\Desktop" 'windows directory where the file will go
WBpath2 = "C:\Users\" & User & "\Desktop" 'windows directory where the file will go

WBName = "BulkUpload" & UserForm1.TextBox5.value & ".csv" 'the name of the file

WBFile = WBpath & "\BulkUploadFiles\" & WBName 'full file path we will be saving the file in
WBFile2 = WBpath2 & "\BulkUploadFiles\" & WBName 'full file path we will be saving the file in

For Each wb In Workbooks 'loop through each open excel workbook and perform the below action
    If wb.Name = WBName Then 'perform the below action only if the currently selected workbook has the same name as the output workbook
        Workbooks(WBName).Close 'close the selected excel workbook
    End If 'done checking if the file is already open
Next 'go to the next open excel workbook

'make the directory to save the bulkupload file to. create it if it doesnt already exist.

Fpath = WBpath & "\BulkUploadFiles\"

If Dir(WBpath2, vbDirectory) <> "" Then

     If Dir(Fpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then

         MkDir Fpath

         Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add 'create the output workbook

         With NewBook 'set the properties for the output workbook
             .Title = WBName 'add the workbook title
             .Subject = WBName 'add the workbook subject
             .SaveAs filename:=WBFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True 'save the output workbook to the assigned directory as a CSV file
         End With 'done setting file properties

    End If
```

End If

Fpath2 = WBpath2 & "\BulkUploadFiles\"

```
If Dir(WBpath2, vbDirectory) <> "" Then

    If Dir(Fpath2, vbDirectory) = "" Then

        MkDir Fpath

        Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add 'create the output workbook

        With NewBook 'set the properties for the output workbook
            .Title = WBName 'add the workbook title
            .Subject = WBName 'add the workbook subject
            .SaveAs filename:=WBFile2, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True 'save the output workbook to the assigned directory as a CSV file
        End With 'done setting file properties

    End If
```

End If
    Workbooks(WBName).Sheets("BulkUpload" & UserForm1.TextBox5.value).Name = "Sheet1" 'rename the first sheet in the output workbook back to Sheet1 so we can reference it correctly later

```
Workbooks(WBName).Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Sheet3" 'add a new sheet to the output workbook

Workbooks(WBName).Sheets("Sheet3").Visible = xlSheetHidden 'hide the new sheet we just made (Sheet3)
```

Comment: "failing" is not a really useful description of what happens when your code runs - exactly *how* (error message?) and *where* (which specific line or lines) does it fail?

Comment: See the edit in my answer - that code worked for me with the one question about having multiple sheets in a CSV.